# explicitly lock row while updating record in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to add explicit lock on row which is currently being updated and I also want to remove the same lock explicitly, after updating that row **in mysql.**

I know there is inbuilt locking system of mysql but I want add it explicitly as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could of course issue a

```
SELECT .. FOR UPDATE
```

statement before the actual update. To release the lock again, commit the transaction. Read about [locking reads here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html). But according to that documentation, that would do the same as simply issuing the `UPDATE` statement itself:

> A SELECT ... FOR UPDATE reads the latest available data, setting exclusive locks on each row it reads. Thus, it sets the same locks a searched SQL UPDATE would set on the rows.